# Drupal language flags not showing up

Tags: php, drupal-6

I have installed the language icons module and the language menu is displaying only the text link but not the flag images. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This is a great time to fire up a tool such as Firebug (which is a free add-in to Firefox).

You need to check the path to the image that should be displayed on the page and make sure that it is pointing to the correct path to your flag resources.

This error usually occurs because you have HTML like this...

```
<a href="/en"><img src="/images/flags/en.png" alt="English"></a>
```

But your file path is actually...

```
/images/language/flags/en.png
```